# Solving a three-part log equation using the log laws

Tags: functions, logarithms

The question asks:

Solve $$\log_5(x-1) + \log_5(x-2) - \log_5(x+6)= 0 $$

I know that according to log laws, addition with the same base is equal to multiplication and subtraction is equal to division (and vice versa)

By doing this I get $$\log_5{(x-1)(x-2)}=0
                                  (x+6)$$

By moving the $x+6$ to the other side it should become zero, ($x+6 \times 0$), however the answer in the textbook moves the $x+6$ to the other side of the equation and then solves. Why am I wrong? And when would you do my method then?

Comment: To answer your original question: the book is *adding* $\log_5(x+6)$ to both sides. You wouldn't multiply the equation $x - 2 = 0$ by $2$ to solve for $x$, would you? Same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

By the same rules you mentioned you should get $$\log_5 \left[(x-1)(x-2)\right]=\log_5[x+6]$$ which after exponentiation with $5$ becomes $$(x-1)(x-2)=x+6$$

If you want to do it by including all three terms in the logarithm, you get the same:
$$\log_5 \left[\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x+6}\right]=0$$ but now you can't just multiply by $x+6$ on both sides and expect it to disappear in the denominator in the $\log$, since it is *inside* the $\log$. What you have to do is to exponentiate both sides to get $$\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x+6}=5^0=1$$
which can of course be rewritten as $$(x-1)(x-2)=x+6$$

So both methods lead to the same result.

Comment: actually with the rules i mentioned, the x+6 would be being divided. It would be underneath the (x-1)(x-2) as subtraction is equal to division. The textbook moves it to the other side like you did, i dont understand why

Comment: That (dividing under the log) would work as well. However, you can choose to just use the rule for two of the terms and then move the $\log_5(x+6)$ to the right hand side.

Comment: If I do the division, then when multiplying x+6 to the other side, it should equal to 0 and thus disappear. This would only leave the left side of my equation equal to zero, This is giving me the wrong answer

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui See my edited answer for an explanation on how to solve it using your method. (Note that you exponentiate with $5$ since it is the base the $\log$ is in.)

Comment: Oh! Wow yeah that explains why, when using my method and the quadratic formula, I got the wrong answer. I've never been asked to solve after setting up the equation like that in school, only to set it up. Thank you, that helps a ton! I have a similar question which i'll ask in a bit

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui Glad I could help! Since you're new to the site (and since I have no shame in life :P) I wanted to let you know that if you like an answer, you can upvote and/or "accept" it (the latter is done by pressing the tick below the up/down-vote arrows next to the answer) and make the answerer very happy. Note that you can only accept one answer per question you ask, but (if you have 15 or more reputation) you can upvote as many answers as you want. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Laws of logarithm needed:

$$ \log_a pq = \log_a p + \log_a q$$
$$ \log_a \left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \log_a p - \log_a q$$

$$\log_b a = 0  \ \implies a = b^0  $$

Using these three laws, your equation can be immediately reduced to:

$$ \log_5 \left(\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x+6}\right) = 0$$

Note: this is the step you got it wrong:
$$\left(\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x+6}\right) = 5^0 = 1 $$

$$ x^2 -3x +2 =x+6$$

Answer (score 0):

or we have $$\log_5((x-1)(x-2))=\log_5(x+6)$$ thus we get $$(x-1)(x-2)=x+6$$

Comment: would the x+6 not be being divided? why is it moved to the other side?

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui when you remove log from both sides, $0$ on the R.H.S becomes $1$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the mistake in your approach is the use of the $\log$ properties.

Let's rewrite the initial equation as $\log_5\left((x-1)(x-2)\cdot \frac{1}{x+6}\right)=0.$

Then we have (since $\log_5 1=0$ and since $\log$ is $1-1$) that $(x-1)(x-2)\cdot \frac{1}{x+6}=1.$

Then, just do some calculations to arrive at the solution. Do not forget to take the restrictions $x-1>0,$ $x-2>0$ and $x+6>0$ (which are equivalent to $x>2$) in order the $\log_5$ to be well defined.

Comment: on a previous test, i was able to multiply two log functions with the same base, and then divide by another function of the same base. Something like this: (x-1)(x-2)/(x+6). why does that not work here?